# Best way to copy /mirror/duplicate mesh?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, duplicate

I spent 4 years using Creo Parametric for CAD and now I'm learning Blender. I'm struggling to make simple rectangular frames. What is the most efficient way to copy this little rectangular block of geometry from A to B? I'm in edit mode, so this is already a single mesh. I'm trying to keep all surfaces flush (coplanar) & aligned. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the *Snap* options. Select the faces of the little block, duplicate them and enable for example *Snapping > Vertex* (other options like *Edges* should also work good in your case). Drag the duplicated faces and while dragging, move the mouse over the target you want to snap to (indicated by a little orange circle, it's a bit hard to see in the gif):

[image]